# Matrix Transformations and Texture mapping coordinates confusion (Beginner)

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, matrix, transformation

I was doing some questions on matrix transformations and texture mapping and I came across two questions for which I dont know how to get the answer. The answer is highlighted with red colour.
(These can be implemented in C++ but before I do it I just wanted to familiarize myself with transformations first)

For matrix transformation shouldnt it have `-1` (top right of the matrix) for the translation instead of `0`
[image]

**EDIT: STILL NEED AN ANSWER TO THE SECOND QUESTION**
My second query is that I am not sure how they got the `y coordinate for point D`

[image]

Comment: Regarding the transformation matrix, I think the answer given is wrong. It should have an additional -1.5 in the x-translation in the matrix c). With a scaling of 0.5 in the x axis, the rectangle would shrink to start from 2.5. To bring it to 1, you need a -1.5 translation

Comment: @Unni Hi man, there is no translation involved according to the answer...have a look at the answer given below, it makes sense.

Comment: I think such a question would find a better place on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the first question:

The resultant image is compressed into half along the x-axis and elongated to twice the length across Y-axis.

Scaling Matrix is what will be the answer. Scaling matrix is a diagonal matrix with elements `{X-scaling, Y-scaling, 1}`.

Now,

```
| 0.5 0 0 |
|  0  2 0 |
|  0  0 1 |
```

is a typical scaling matrix. It scales the x-axis by 0.5 (that is it stretches(compresses) the x-axis into half). This is noticeable in Matrix(1,1).

THe scaling across Y-direction is given in Matrix(2,2). The `2` over there implies, the Y-axis is elongated 2 times.

**NOTE**:
In this question there is **no translation** involved. Notice that simple scaling makes it seem like translation.

Comment: Makes sense...I think it occurs because first the object is translated back to the origin and then scaled and then back..

Comment: Actually, the image is scaled **without** translation to center of the object. Going your way (and considering only X-direction for the moment), the first translation will be `-3`. Next scaling, and re-translate by `+3`. This would result in the image getting scaled in the same location. There wont be that 'apparent' translation in it :)

Comment: oh yeeees! my bad my bad...wonder why they make it tricky. If the object started off in the origin to begin with then there would be no probs at all...do you know the answer to second question =)

Comment: Glad you figured that out. About the second question, I  think, the answer is wrong. There is no repetition of the texture along the Y-direction. It makes me think the Y-texture-coordinate is just `1`.

Comment: I think the same thing but the answers were given by my lecturer, its unlikely he made a mistake with that one. But ill email him and see if he has and then update this post =)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to the second question.

The corner above point B must have the y-coordinate 1, since otherwise you wouldn't see the bottom face. Hence for the point D you need the y-coordinate 2. If you take the line from B to the corner point to D, then the textre image is repeated two times.